# Accessing http-server project on Cpanel

Tags: node.js, angularjs, cpanel, httpserver

I uploaded a simple Node JS / AngularJS / http-server project on Cpanel, I don't know how to access it, I tried (mysite).com/rainbowchat it opens a white page, and (mysite).com/rainbowchat:8080 gives error 404

It works without a problem on local, by running node ./node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "sdk-angular-sample",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "RC Angular Sample",
  "main": "index.js", //PS: there is no index.js but an index.html that is accessed by the http-server module
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server -o -p 8080"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Rainbow-CPaaS/Rainbow-Web-SDK-Samples.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "rainbow",
    "CPaaS",
    "SDK"
  ],
  "author": "Alc",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.7.9",
    "rainbow-web-sdk": "^1.64.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "http-server": "0.9.0"
  }
}
```

Cpanel NodeJS configuration:

[image]